# PHP Foreach loop too slow when applied on large arrays

Tags: php, arrays, performance, foreach

So, basically, i have to loop thought an array of 25000 items, then compare each item with another array's ID and if the ID's from the first array and the second match then create another array of the matched items. That looks something like this.

```
foreach ($all_games as $game) {
  foreach ($user_games_ids as $user_game_id) {
     if ($user_game_id == $game["appid"]) {
         $game_details['title'][] = $game["title"];
         $game_details['price'][] = $game["price"];
         $game_details['image'][] = $game["image_url"];
         $game_details['appid'][] = $game["appid"];
     }
  }
}
```

I tested this loop with only 2500 records from the first array ($all_games) and about 2000 records from the second array ($user_games_ids) and as far as i figured, it takes about **10 seconds** for the execution of that chunk of code, only the loops execution. Is that normal? Should that take that long or I'm I approaching the issue from the wrong side? Is there a way to reduce that time? Because when i apply that code to 25000 records that time will significantly increase.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

**EDIT:** So there is no confusion, I can't use the DB query to improve the performance, although, i have added all 25000 games to the database, i can't do the same for the user games ids. There is no way that i know to get all of the users through that API i'm accessing, and even there is, that would be really a lot of users. I get user games ids on the fly when a user enters it's ID in the form and based on that i use file_get_contents to obtain those ids and then cross reference them with the database that stores all games. Again, that might not be the best way, but only one i could think of at this point.

Comment: Try to query up only games having the `user_game_id` from the very beginning so you won't get redundant data. Further performance increase can be obtained by paginating results...

Comment: 2500 x 2000 is 5,000,000 iterations. That is 5 million.

Comment: What is your problem you try to solve? Whys don't you use DB?

Comment: I'll edit the question a bit so it is more clear, sorry guys. Basically, i was looking for a way to avoid that that other foreach if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you re-index the `$game` array by `appid` using `array_column()`, then you can reduce it to one loop and just check if the data isset...

```
$game = array_column($game,null,"appid");
foreach ($user_games_ids as $user_game_id) {
    if (isset( $game[$user_game_id])) {
        $game_details['title'][] = $game[$user_game_id]["title"];
        $game_details['price'][] = $game[$user_game_id]["price"];
        $game_details['image'][] = $game[$user_game_id]["image_url"];
        $game_details['appid'][] = $game[$user_game_id]["appid"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, perferct! That reduced it from 10 seconds to 0.011001110076904 miliseconds! :)